# Android is there any way to lock socket with only one device?

Tags: android, sockets

I am creating a single test application which is using sockets to create a connection between two devices and transfer some data (a kind of messaging app).

My question is: 
Is there any way which I won't let other devices connect to a device, when it is already connected with another one. For example I have two devices `A` and `B` and they are connected. I don't wanna let device `C` to connect to any of them.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seeing how A and B need to be listening in order for C to connect - i.e. something like ServerSocket, simply stop listening for incoming connections once it successfully makes a connection between A and B?

Without your code for how you connect I can't tell much more, but that should be how to do it.

Comment: The thing is that I am using ServerSocket for listening on specific port...but I'm using a custom class to detect all online users in the current wifi, and gets all their available ports and ips. So I need somehow to listen only for a specific device, not all of them.Because now, while everyone in the same wifi has my ip and port can send me messages.